# Buidling with grunt: grunt-rev task changes my images by adding a random hash and thus prevents my html from identify them

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

This is my html:

```
     <img src="../images/zulazlogo.png" alt="image1" >
```

However after running grunt build the image name is:

5cadd58e.zulazlogo.png

This is due to the grunt-rev task.

is there a way to tweak the html to include a build statement to change the file according to the new name? something like:

```
<img src="../images/@@hashzulalogo.png" alt="image1">
```

Comment: The docs say "Use the rev task together with yeoman/grunt-usemin for cache busting of static files in your app. This allows them to be cached forever by the browser." and it looks like "yeoman/grunt-usemin" is what changes your version files, no?

Comment: I am not sure. When I commented out the images section of the grunt-rev task the images names remained.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried commenting out the grunt-rev images sections?

```
rev: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      src: [
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
//            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Commenting that line out means to refuse to understand how the image files renaming mechanism works

Comment: To whoever flagged my comment without even showing up and try to point out his argument: shame on you, coward, shame on you.